How to fix the CrowdStrike blue screen?
There is an ongoing issue where a bad CrowdStrike update has caused systems worldwide to fail to boot Windows and blue screen to WinRE after the failed boot attempts
For machines affected by this, how to resolve the issue and have them boot normally?

I'm a little conflicted, its an 'easy' answer but its also literally the official support answer. "All possible" solutions could range from the official answer, to quitting tech and becoming a goat herder tho

Hello, in order to fix crowdstrike BSOD, you must delete the file named C-00000291-*** that is located in c:/windows/system32/drivers/Crowdstrike. this is a workarround for now, I precise this is a workarround

I note that there's official docs floating around, and reddit posts and such. I really would expect answers that are not just the official support answer or worse, answers from another source copied entirely

I fixed it this morning by just renaming the CSAgent.net, but that probably kills CrowdStrike entirely. i'll wait until they fix the issue, then install it again.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not within our scope. It falls under "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks", specifically corporate IT that is using Crowdstrike. It is not up to the end user to resolve corporate IT issues.

@MC10 while I agree in principle, this site gets far more traffic that Server Fault and, for the current issue, having this answer here seems like a helpful thing.

@music2myear the post can be kept around while closed.

I am strongly opposing closing the question in this huge case. Many corporate support services were (or still are) unable to help their users so they have no other way but fixing their systems by themselves.

Its two and a half months later, I found one windows VM busy crowdstriking itself at work.  These instructions are still useful and relevant.


In many corporate networks, end users are not expected/allowed to maintain their own systems and there may be potential wrinkles in corporate environments (compliance requirements, BitLocker, etc.)

Please determine what the appropriate steps are for your environment and whether rectification of the issue is self-service, requires you do it yourself, or if it's even necessary. 



Fixes:


Microsoft Recovery Tool:
Microsoft has released a tool that builds a bootable recovery system, requiring a USB drive and Admin privledges on a 64bit Windows OS with 8GB of free space:

Bitlocker Only:  Recovery key for each machine required

Get the Recovery Key ID from WinRE:

See advanced repair options → Troubleshoot → Advanced options → Command Prompt


Go to the Microsoft account's Device List

Log in with work/school credentials
Select: Windows PC → View BitLocker Keys
Find matching: Recovery ID → Get: Recovery Key 




Reported Issues:  See comments on linked Microsoft Article

If WDK is installed, do the recovery system generation from a clean system 






Manual Removal:
CrowdStrike's Director of Overwatch provides this workaround for the "faulty channel file":

Boot to Safe Mode or WinRE's Command Prompt from the WinRE blue screen:

Safe Mode:  See advanced repair options → Troubleshoot → Advanced options → Startup Settings → Restart → Options menu: Safe Mode F4 / 4 
WinRE: Command Prompt  See advanced repair options → Troubleshoot → Advanced options → Command Prompt

BitLocker Only:

Get the Recovery Key ID from the screen
Go to the Microsoft account's Device List

Log in with work/school credentials
Select: Windows PC → View BitLocker Keys
Find matching: Recovery ID → Get: Recovery Key


Enter Recovery Key within WinRE → Enter 


If a machine is stuck on a BSOD and not auto-booted to WinRE:

Reboot machine: Press and hold power button to power off → Release → Power on
Once Windows' bootloader begins loading Windows, repeat Step 1 twice in a row

Windows will auto-boot to WinRE upon two failed attempts by the Windows bootloader to load Windows 








Delete file matching C-00000291*.sys within:
%WinDir%\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike


Safe Mode:

Open an Admin terminal:  +R → Open: powershell → Ctrl+Shift+OK
Delete file:
Remove-Item -Path "$env:WinDir\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*.sys" -Force


Reboot:
Shutdown /f /r /t 0





WinRE Command Prompt:  (C: is usually not the OS partition mount point in WinRE)

Obtain mount point of the OS partition:
::# Launch DiskPart:
    DiskPart

  rem # List all volumes [partitions]:
        Lis Vol

  rem # Close DiskPart:
        Exit


Delete file:
Del /f /q "<OSdriveLetter>:\Windows\System32\drivers\CrowdStrike\C-00000291*.sys"


Reboot: Close Command Prompt → Continue to Windows <#> 




Normally boot to Windows 



It's mentioned some machines may self-recover between auto-booting to WinRE since a fix has been pushed out

Azure's help pages recommends rebooting VMs up to 15x as a potential workaround 


It might be possible to boot a WinPE [Windows installer] or WinRE CD/DVD/PXE/USB to do the necessary changes, but this isn't guaranteed since these are business machines

Windows installer: Open a terminal once the GUI loads via Shift+F10




Quick note - as a ongoing issue, and something rapidly changing, and other circumstances, I feel like having this as a 'community' owned post made sense. I've stuck a community wiki on this, and feel free to update the post as new information comes in.

If your C drive is locked by Bitlocker, there are some additional steps you have to take to get to the command prompt.  From the Recovery Screen -> Click Advanced Repair Options -> Click Troubleshoot -> Click Advanced Options -> Select Command prompt.  Get the Recovery Key Id from the screen.  Go to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list.  Log in with your work/school credentials.  Select the Windows PC.  Click on View Bitlocker Keys.  Find the matching Recovery Id Id and get the Recovery Key.  Enter that in your PC and hit enter to get into the command prompt.  Then follow the steps.

If you're in a company/have an AD or don't have access you might need to call your helpdesk for the bitlocker key.

If your computers are configured to PXE boot and you have a PXE server on the network (and the computers are on the corporate network), there are PXE boot images I've found referenced on r/sysadmin that delete the offending file, meaning all you need to do is turn the computer on and it'll "fix itself".

If your system is locked down to the point that you're using CrowdStrike, I'd imagine it's also locked down so you can't boot from user devices.  How does Microsoft expect a bootable USB to be useful?

@MarkRansom: There's some admin who knows the firmware password, giving him a exemption from the boot media restriction, and an automated tool in his hands allows fixing computers at a much higher rate than if he needed to perform the manual instructions listed here

While the community wiki answer outlines the basic steps for the workaround/repair, they may be too difficult or time-consuming to perform on a team- or org-wide basis. Our company just added the CrowdStrike BSOD fix to our EasyRE live repair CDs/USBs, and can fix this with only one click (full repair is under 60 seconds, boot time included). The important part is that it doesn't require any credentials (as it's not Windows-based) and will work even if you can't boot into Safe Mode (as some orgs have enabled the CrowdStrike deployment option that blocks booting with CS integration disabled for further security).
If you need to deploy this org-wide, it's possible to boot into the ISO via a PXE network server, too.
Here's a screenshot of the automated repair picking up on this particular bad update and rolling it back:

Disclosure: worked on this fix and affiliated with the company in question (NeoSmart Technologies), but AFAIK SuperUser accepts such answers as long as the disclosure is in place!

This solution only works if you are NOT using BitLocker or Device Encryption. Many Enterprises use BitLocker and affected CrowdStrike product is an Enterprise solution

I've created an automated PowerShell script based on the CrowdStrike's documentation to fix the BSOD issue. It will wait for the machine to be online, check for the relevant files, reboot into safe mode, delete the files, reboot out of safe mode and verify that the files are gone. I hope it helps and would love feedback.
https://github.com/systemfrontier/Automated-CrowdStrike-Falcon-BSOD-Remediation-Tool
As someone else mentioned, this won't work if BitLocker prevents a normal boot into Windows.

Since PowerShell isn't included in WinPE/WinRE, and this issue prevented machines from even booting to Windows, this would benefit from being a .cmd script. For running in Safe Mode, a command can be added to run the PowerShell script itself within powershell.
